# OpenGL - how to draw an array of lines fast, given in a special form?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, graph

I have a 2D array of lines in following form:

```
lines[MAX_LINES][MAX_POINT_INDICES];
```

For example, it may look like:

```
lines[1] = {2, 3, 0, 0, 0}; //lines from 1 to 2, from 1 to 3, 0=END
lines[2] = {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //lines from 2 to 3, 0=END
lines[3] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 0}; //lines from 3 to 4, 3->5, 3->6, 3->7, 0 means END
...
```

So, each line is defined like a triangle fan. Now, I would like to draw all these lines using OpenGL, but I can't find any fast way how to do it, except as sequentially iterating through each of the row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sequentially iterating over the array to get the points is a solution. What makes you feel it is not fast enough?

Comment: @loxxy I thought maybe OpenGL supports such format. I spend number of clocks to prepare lines of each row to be used with glDrawElements(GL_LINES,...

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to draw this thing without iterating through it. If you want to draw it with few calls, you will probably have to change your data structure to something that could be supplied directly as a GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Answer (score 0):

Like what loxxy said, iterating over the array you laid out is the fastest way to do it. Iteration isn't slow, that's just the way things are drawn in OpenGL - linearly.